# Magento 2 - Issue in Generate data which will use for performance testing

Tags: magento2, tax-rates, tax-rule

When I generate data to use for performance testing by running following command

```
php bin/magento setup:perf:generate-fixtures
```

It gives the following error in Tax rates step

[image]

Any help, experience and knowledge sharing would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope the error was due to duplication of tax rates as you have installed Magento along with sample data. So you can proceed either by try removing sample data or truncating the `tax_calculation` table. Once done this error will be gone. You might also face similar errors when you continue to create data with sample data installed. I have tried this command in Magento without sample data and I got the data created without any errors [image]

Comment: You figured out the right solution. Accepting and upvoting your answer so it helps other readers as well.